# Fail to run Angular Project due to incompatible version

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error 'Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.' while I try to run an Angular project. My specs are as follows:

Angular CLI: 7.0.6
Node: 14.16.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.4

... animations, cdk, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... language-service, material, material-moment-adapter
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

### Package Information

@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.6

@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1102.8

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.6

@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.6

@angular-devkit/core              7.0.6

@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.6

@angular/cli                      7.0.6

@angular/compiler-cli             11.2.9

@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.19

@ngtools/webpack                  11.2.8

@schematics/angular               7.0.6

@schematics/update                0.10.6

rxjs                              6.3.3

typescript                        3.1.6

webpack                           4.44.2

I'm not sure to which versions should I go. Updating '@angular-devkit/build-angular' haven't helped so far. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the @angular-devkit/build-angular to "0.7.4" and @angular/compiler-cli to 7.0.4. It worked then. In case someone faces the problem, try to match the version of Angular rather than upgrading those packages.(If your Angular has a lower version than the mentioned packages)